# What font is used in this image, please?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

I downloaded this font in another pc, but i don't remember the name. Please, help me to find.

From http://ohnath.tumblr.com/

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have a collection of font identification resources, and it is a good idea to try that first. Edit your question and let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increases. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you loor for [FATC font](http://www.dafont.com/fatc.font) -

[image]

[image]